# Can I set noatime for my XEN guest OS partition? Will it work?

Tags: unix, io, virtualization, xen

I have a VPS in cloud environment based on XEN Virtualization platform.

/etc/fstab looks like that:

```
LABEL=PRGMRDISK1   /    ext3    errors=remount-ro       0       0
```

As far as I know IO can pretty easily become a bottleneck if some other VPS neighbor will use it intensively(IO bandwidth is a shared resource for multiple guest VPS).

Can I add `noatime,nodiratime` to /etc/fstab partition declaration to save some IO load? Will it work?

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended to use `noatime` and `nodiratime` in your domU indeed, also it's good to have some other tweaks in mind, here's a quick list:

In *domU* (Xen guest):

- In fstab have `noatime,nodiratime`.
- Change the default scheduler to `noop` (add `elevator=noop` to your kernel boot parameters).

In *dom0* (Xen host):

- In fstab have `noatime,nodiratime`.
- Change the default scheduler to `anticipatory` (add `elevator=anticipatory` to your kernel boot parameters).

To get even more IO throughput you can use other quirks as using LVM volumes to mount straight into the XEN host and stuff like that, but for starters those tricks should give you good enough IO performance.

Comment: which is the file for dom0 (Xen host)?

Comment: also I read somewhere, that the `elevator=` option is deprecated by now?